# Regex in apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

We have a server that has a few aliases and I've been trying to write a regex that'll match each of these hostnames for a rewrite rule:

```
dev.domain.com      
www.dev.domain.com    
dev.www.domain.com
```

Right now I have the "I dont really know regex" solution of 
`(dev\.www|www\.dev|dev)\.domain\.com`

It works, but I know its the least elegant way to do it. The server has about 120 other aliases so it's important I don't do something like `(.*)domain\.com` and match something like sales.domain.com by accident.

Using a non-capture group I was able to get 2 of the 3 matched but never all 3. I was trying things like `(?:www|dev)\.domain\.com` but I can't figure out (or find on google) a way to ignore the order. I might be going about it completely the wrong way as well.

Comment: Using a simple clear solution can be better than a clever hard to understand solution. The "I don't know regex" method is easy to understand. Why complicate things and risk matching hosts you didn't mean to?

Comment: To elaborate slightly. You currently have (AB|BA|A)D. About the best you're going to get is (AB|B?A)D without making your regex longer than it started.

Comment: jhnc you make a good point. I tend to overcomplicate things often. I'll stick with the simple solution, thank you.